# With POI Word API, how to repeat a table heading on subsequent pages?

Tags: java, ms-word, apache-poi

I am using Apache POI 3.12 for generating a Word document containing a XWPFTable.
In the MS Word interface you can repeat a table heading on subsequent pages by checking a property on the table itself.

How do you do the same using the XWPFTable API ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In [JWord](http://www.independentsoft.de/jword) that is set on  Row level. There is method

```
row.setHeader(true);
```

Something similar should exist in the POI.

Comment: Great ! You are right, there is an API on the row level: `row.setRepeatHeader(true);`